# PHP - XML to CSV remove XML Whitespace

Tags: php, xml, csv

I'm trying to convert a XML file to CSV using PHP, but I have a problem with whitespaces for some values inside a tag.
This is the XML:

```
<Product>
<Code>1234</Code>
<Name>product name</Name>
<Category>some category</Category>
<Manufacturer>manufacturer</Manufacturer>
<Price>                 100</Price>
<Stock>1</Stock>
</Product>
```

As you can see, there's a lot of whitespace inside the Price tag, which messes with my CSV formatting. I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
$Product->Price = preg_replace("/>\s+</", "><", $Product->Price);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the "/>" in the regexp meant to match?

Comment: Are you using an XML parser to parse the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `trim()`. From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the
>   beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will
>   strip these characters:
>
> " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space. "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a
>   tab. "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed). "\r" (ASCII 13
>   (0x0D)), a carriage return. "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
>   "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is looking for `<`, but it should be looking for a number. Try

```
$Product->Price = preg_replace("/>\s+[0-9]</", "><", $Product->Price);
```

You can test out php preg_* functions on this page: http://www.fullonrobotchubby.co.uk/random/preg_tester/preg_tester.php

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use some parsers that others have taken time to write:

- http://codestips.com/php-xml-to-csv/
- http://www.magicparser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Think you're over complicating it...

```
$Product->Price = preg_replace("/\s/","",$Product->Price);
```

Comment: Very True, `trim()` is actually a more elegant solution, mine was just following his already existing code.